# Declaring existing data types in the Python library

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I find the following line often in the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module of Python 2.7:

```
_int = int
```

After that line, the code uses the new type `_int` instead of `int`. For example:

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None):
    if random is None:
        random = self.random
    _int = int
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = _int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

In the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module, I found this:

```
####################################################################
# NOTE: Everything below here is deprecated.  Use string methods instead.
# This stuff will go away in Python 3.0.

[..]

# for a bit of speed
_float = float
_int = int
_long = long
```

Why does the library use `_int` instead of `int`? Why is that faster than just using the built-in `int`?

Answer (score 6):

Global variables are always looked up by name, while local variables get accessed by index, which is much faster.

Illustration:

```
>>> def foo(s):
...     return int(s)
...
>>> def bar(s, int=int):
...     return int(s)
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (int)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (int)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

The above works as micro-optimisation because the local `int` gets resolved during function definition, rather than function execution.

In your example, `_int = int` is done during function execution, so you still have to do get `int` through `LOAD_GLOBAL` once when calling shuffle, but you save on each consecutive call to `int` inside the loop.